# How to match all string types with std::is_same_v

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, if-constexpr

I'm trying to use templates to generify a method. However I'm struggling to match string types like string `char *` literals. See the following code example:

```
template<typename ValueType>
void match_data_type(ValueType value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>, bool>) {
        std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>, char>) { // Useless?
        std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>, char *>) {
        std::cout << "char *" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>, char[]>) { // Useless?
        std::cout << "char[]" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>, std::string>) {
        std::cout << "std::string" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not matched!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
match_data_type(false);
char *string_buffer = "Text";
match_data_type(string_buffer);
match_data_type("Test");
std::string standard_string = "Test";
match_data_type(standard_string);
```

Output:

```
bool
char *
Not matched!
std::string
```

The surprising part to me is the `Not matched!` output since I passed a string literal directly into the method and it didn't match any of the cases.

<s>1)</s>Is there any `constexpr` check which matches all types of `char *`? Then I need another case for `std::string` objects so I can pass the `.c_str()` into the respective legacy method which expects `char *` as its argument.

<s>2) Is there a way to statically fail the compilation if none of the cases are matched? (e.g. the `else` branch is taken). `static_assert(false)` in the `else` branch does not work since it will always take effect, regardless of the passed parameter type.</s>

Comment: A string literal is a `const char[n]` where `n` is the number of characters in the literal, including the `\0`.

Comment: `"Test"` is of type `const char[5]`.

Comment: only later I realized that I am actually not answering your question. The title is not the same as the question you ask in the body of the question. 2. could be a seperate question, it doesn't need the rest of the question as context to be a meaningful question

Comment: `char *string_buffer = "Text";` is wrong, missing `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are constant.

The type of `"hello"` is `char const[6]`, which would decay (since you're taking by value) to `char const*`. You have to check against that, not `char*`.

---

For the rest of the code, the `char` check isn't useless (you could certainly call `match_data_type('c')`) but the `char[]` one is -- the parameter will never have array type, since it's a value.

More broadly, `std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>` will always be just `ValueType` unless you're explicitly providing that parameter -- since that type will never be deduced to be a reference type or have qualifiers.